# Could not download appcompat-v7.aar after upgrading to Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I updated to the new `Android Studio 3.0`, i updated the gradle plugin to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

and the gradle wrapper:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

and my module's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

when i sync my project i get this error:

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not download appcompat-v7.aar
>   (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0)

when I click on details:

> Could not download appcompat-v7.aar
>   (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0)
>   Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'XXX/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar'.
>   For input string: "

I tried with other dependencies and it works (Retrofit).

Comment: did you set `allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}`

Comment: I work behind a proxy, these two repositories are added to the company interne repository and i fetch them. Before upgrading, i can download the app compat support library

Answer (score 1):

Disable offline mode in "Settings" -> "Gradle", then try Gradle Sync. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the root gradle.build file to as below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Mainly the google has moved the newer repos to its new independent domain

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle in repositories add google repository:

```
repositories {
     google()
}
```

and

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

and in defaultConfig

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```